# Heroku h12 Timeout Error with PG / Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am getting a nasty h12 (timeout error) when trying to insert into my db.

```
2017-01-25T00:22:24.764591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api" host=kujaflow.herokuapp.com request_id=fb69dfdf-12ef-4dc8-8feb-45bef0c26746 fwd="71.125.214.77" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30005ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I have no idea why this is happening. My node code looks good from what I gather. I have edited out the user/pass info ....

```
var express = require('express');
var pg = require('pg');

var dbuser = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var dbpassword = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var dbname = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var dbhost = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var dbport = 5432;

var dbconnect = {
    user: dbuser, 
    password: dbpassword,
    host: dbhost,
    database: dbname, 
    port: dbport
};

var router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


/* api */
router.post('/api', function(req, res, next) {

    var latitude = req.body.location.coords.latitude;
    // console.log("latitude: " + latitude);
    var longitude = req.body.location.coords.longitude;
    var heading = req.body.location.coords.heading;
    var timestamp = req.body.location.timestamp;
    var uuid = req.body.location.uuid;
    var is_moving = req.body.location.is_moving;

    pg.connect(dbconnect, function(err, client, done) {

        client.query('INSERT INTO kujadata (latitude, longitude) VALUES ($1, $2);',[latitude, longitude], function (err, result) {
            client.end();
        });

    });

});


router.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'API' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the entire route code you have for your `/api` route?

Comment: Updated @rdegges thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, the issue here is that you aren't properly 'ending' your `/api` route. When you're using express, you need to explicitly send a response to the client.

Here's how you can rewrite it:

```
router.post('/api', function(req, res, next) {

  var latitude = req.body.location.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = req.body.location.coords.longitude;
  var heading = req.body.location.coords.heading;
  var timestamp = req.body.location.timestamp;
  var uuid = req.body.location.uuid;
  var is_moving = req.body.location.is_moving;

  pg.connect(dbconnect, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('INSERT INTO kujadata (latitude, longitude) VALUES ($1, $2);', [latitude, longitude], function (err, result) {
      client.end();
      return res.end();
    });
  });

});
```

Notice the explicit call to `res.end()`? This is what tells express "hey, the request is done, tell the client we're through!"

The reason your Heroku logs show a 30 second timeout is because your request never "ended", and Heroku will return a 503 automatically if your request doesn't finish within 30 seconds.

Comment: THANK YOU! I feel that should be documented a little more prominently ;)

Comment: Hi @rdegges.. how does this work for GET too? I am getting the same error with a get later in my routes file.    router.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {
  
 pg.connect(dbconnect, function(err, client, done) {

  client.query('SELECT * FROM kujadata', function(err, result) {
   res.render('api',{title: 'Recorded data', geolocs: result.rows });
   client.end();
   done();
  });

 });

});

Comment: Im rendering a res file this time so I am guessing that res.end is not needed?

Comment: Correct -- if you're using `res.render()`, `res.json()`, etc. -- then `res.end()` is not needed. You basically NEED to call `res` in some way in order to end the request.